# How to use ESC/POS Commands for QR-Code Print Greater then 100 Characters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, printing

I Have use (PT-280)Ble Printer.

I Have already QR-Code Print Less Then 100 Character. Successfully.

I Have not able to Print QR-Code for Greater than 100 Characters..

I Have use  ESC/Pos Commands for QR-Code Print.

This is my Code:

```
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"To download the free app Google Translate by Google, Inc., get iTunes now. ... Google translate is very useful application. ... It is a very nice app as it translates the whole text immediately."];
int store_len = (int )content.length + 3;
int pl = (store_len % 256);
[escCmd addPrintMode: 0x1d];
[escCmd addQRCodeSizewithpL:0 withpH:0 withcn:49 withyfn:67 withn:10];
[escCmd addQRCodeLevelwithpL:0 withpH:0 withcn:49 withyfn:69 withn:51];
[escCmd addQRCodeSavewithpL:pl withpH:0 withcn:49 withyfn:80 withm:48 withData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[escCmd addQRCodePrintwithpL:3 withpH:pl+3 withcn:49 withyfn:81 withm:48];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be any limitation of QR code.
I found Gprinter app on AppStore, and it works with my PT-280, but when I try to make QR code, there is a description like this ' put 1 - 60 character'.